# Spring MVC is there a way to retrieve full path from mapping file/**?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to have a mapping that will match `file/`+ any path, for example `file/image.jpg` or `file/a/b/c/image.jpg` and i want to receive full path after `file/` i can do it if i have only 1 path variable:

```
file/{file_name}
```

But don't know how to do it for my case. I know that i can map just `file/**` and then retrieve path like this:

```
 (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
```

But i'm looking for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be using `spring-mvc` interceptor

Before creating the HTTP request, encode the `file_name` path variable using `URLEncoder` that way you can send it with slashes and the request is processed by the correct handler. Then you need to create an interceptor whose method is invoked before the controller method. In the interceptor you would decode the path variable back with `URLDecoder` and set it back as an attribute. The attributes name is specified by `HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE` constant and it contains a Map of all path variables.

The interceptor needs to implement `HandlerInterceptor` interface or extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` if you don't want to implement all methods of the interface.

Something like this

```
public class UrlDecodeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

private static final String ATTRIBUTE_VARIBLE_PATH = "file_name";

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

    if (pathVariables.containsKey(ATTRIBUTE_VARIBLE_PATH)) {
        String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(pathVariables.get(ATTRIBUTE_VARIBLE_PATH), "UTF-8");

        pathVariables.put(ATTRIBUTE_VARIBLE_PATH, decoded);
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

By default, `spring-mvc` decodes URLs on its own. You need to disable it in the **spring-servlet.xml** or whatever your servlet config file is.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
   <property name="urlDecode" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Then you need to register the `UrlDecodeInterceptor` as an interceptor in the same file

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="urlDecodeInterceptor" class="path.to.your.package.UrlDecodeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In the end, your controller handler would look like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{file_name}")
public String someMethodName(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {

    System.out.println(fileName); // should contain decoded file_name

    return null
}
```

Comment: I... don't think it's more elegant solution :)

Comment: It might seem complicated. But it is more elegant than handling all `/file/*` requests using a single handler. At least in terms of scalability

Comment: @saroff As I am thinking about it. You might as well skip the interceptor part, disable the autodecoding, send the `file_name` encoded and decode the path variable in the handler. I proceeded from one problem I solved using the interceptor some time ago. But it was slightly more complicated than your case is